# Fetch Blob Imagen con React Native Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

tengo una imagen en un enpoint como este.

```
https://d1na8u9bbyf6pn.cloudfront.net/twt-uat1/MUS2014123113584242167/69093975526/105000000204082.jpeg?Expires=1539883894&Signature=ONFNJ1XTY3FOLUIMDnrcpR7~Awuobkwx~P5Ab~4hYx5bnVf5fSKwAzbobWZNnYrmzVXHGiyUmVEfRSvuZtseaMJfx6y1Bs9oI5ewuLRf-r0zMn25gFsN228FQ3IBaki3BsXJXQ-d~yVfhlkA6rIxQ1bHxnJ0VOgxEr6UU9g8gny2NIHwQTppJwFQYyAOtY1yBQ7KtlWp-WcasQVcCZn0H7tG59a7rpBCFUcfaFozQS0Dduizyl972vuHBY6V6o2KiCTWRrTNnXvFMLTfzVYb8UXl9USbwHP2nGvnqAfYhYIlm4KeYcJU4VZC66iWypcOPrpfJkdokHmgXltkbJJHbA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJER34WYXWHOJ2NZQ
```

Pero cuando el fetch al enpoint y luego el .blob me dice que la imagen pesa 0kb, hay alguna manera de conseguir la imagen de un endpoint para poder utilizarla en React Native Expo ?

La función para pedir la imagen al enpoint es la siguiente, pero me devuelve que la imagen tiene 0kb.

```
getImage = () => {
  const urlImage =
    "https://d1na8u9bbyf6pn.cloudfront.net/twt-uat1/MUS2014123113584242167/69093975526/105000000204082.jpeg?Expires=1539883894&Signature=ONFNJ1XTY3FOLUIMDnrcpR7~Awuobkwx~P5Ab~4hYx5bnVf5fSKwAzbobWZNnYrmzVXHGiyUmVEfRSvuZtseaMJfx6y1Bs9oI5ewuLRf-r0zMn25gFsN228FQ3IBaki3BsXJXQ-d~yVfhlkA6rIxQ1bHxnJ0VOgxEr6UU9g8gny2NIHwQTppJwFQYyAOtY1yBQ7KtlWp-WcasQVcCZn0H7tG59a7rpBCFUcfaFozQS0Dduizyl972vuHBY6V6o2KiCTWRrTNnXvFMLTfzVYb8UXl9USbwHP2nGvnqAfYhYIlm4KeYcJU4VZC66iWypcOPrpfJkdokHmgXltkbJJHbA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJER34WYXWHOJ2NZQ";
  const token = "XXXXXXXX";

  let obj = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: token
    }
  };

  fetch(url, obj)
    .then(response => {
      return response.blob();
    })
    .then(function(miBlob) {
      var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(miBlob);
      miImagen.src = objectURL;
    });
};
```

Comment: Sería super si pudieses regalarnos parte del código de lo que estás intentando, ya sabemos que estás haciendo una llamada a una url, pero no podemos saber de qué forma lo estás haciendo porque no nos dices. No sé tampoco la razón por la que lo haces así cuando puedes mostrar una imagen de la forma `source={{ uri: 'www.urlimagen.com' }}`. Por otro lado, sería tambien bueno si pusieras una url de acceso público

Comment: He subido la función que uso para pedir la imagen.

Comment: Si intentaste de la forma en la que te comento con `uri`?

Comment: No funciona por que es un endpoint con token entonces hay que hace un fetch a la imagen.

Comment: Actualmente, también tengo ese problema ¿lo llegaste a resolver?